# link_to is not triggering the action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I've the below in `index.html.erb` (Just the important part ad `post` is declared)

```
<%=link_to yay_post_path(post), :remote=>true, class:'btn-default btn' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
<% end %>
<%=link_to nah_post_path(post), :remote=>true, class:'btn btn-default' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
<%end %>
```

And this in `route.rb`

```
resources :posts do
   member do
    put 'yay', to: 'posts#yay'
    put 'nah', to: 'posts#nah'
  end
end
```

And this in `PostsController`

```
  def yay
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.liked_by current_user
    @redirect_to @post
  end

  def nah
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.downvote_from current_user
    @redirect_to @post
  end
```

Note that the above methods don't have their own views. They are just custom methods.

When I click on the link, I get 404 Error saying

```
cannot find /post/1/yay
```

What is the fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare the path in the router with html method `put`, so you have to adjust your link accordingly. A normal link is always http `GET`, but rails will help you when you write:

```
<%=link_to yay_post_path(post), remote: true, method: :put, class:'btn-default btn' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
<% end %>
```

so you have to explicitly add the http-method if it differs from the default.

[EDIT: handling js in controller]
To handle the js in the controller there are two options:

#### return nothing

```
def yay
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js do 
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
      @post.liked_by current_user
      head :ok
    end
  end
end
```

Note: this will return http status 406 for html calls, which is what I would want :)

A more standard approach would be to

```
def yay
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.liked_by current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { @redirect_to @post }
    format.js   { head :ok }
  end
end
```

But that depends on what you want to support (e.g. allow to fallback to standard html or not).

If you want to update the view, which I would want (otherwise they could go on yay-ing and nay-ing, unless you handle that browser-side), you could do something like:

```
def yay
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js do 
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
      @post.liked_by current_user
    end
  end
end
```

and add a view called `yay.js.erb` containing

```
$('#yays_and_nays').hide()
```

or e.g. update a part of the view

```
$(#yays_and_nays').replaceWith('<% escape_javascript(render 'yay_or_nayed_status') %>');
```

Comment: Plus 1, but I'm getting `400: Bad Request` what should I do?

Comment: You are not handling or allowing `format.js` in the controller? The redirect does not make sense for js. So remove the `remote: true` or handle `format.js`.

Comment: So I have to use `fomat.js`. Okay, got it. Thanks.

Comment: I am using empty one `respond_to do |format|
        format.html {}
        format.js   {}
        format.json {}
    end` as I don't want to return anything, but this is causing internal error 500, How can I implement this? Sorry, I'm new to rails, btw.

Comment: No problem, I extended my answer a bit. In short: use `head :ok` for js.

Answer (score 0):

in your routes...

```
put 'yay', to: 'posts#yay'
```

its `PUT`,So you need to include `:method=>"put"`in `link_to` as well..refer this [ApiDock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)